# swift2にて、キーボードのreturnキーを押したらキーボードを隠したいが、コードが機能しません。

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var item: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

        toDoList.append(item.text!)

        item.text = ""

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }
    **func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        item.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }**
}
```

太字の部分で、隠れるはずだと思ったのですが、何度returnキーを押してもキーボードが隠れません。
ちなみにキーボード以外の部分を押せばキーボードは隠れます。

Comment: `UITextField`のoutletとdelegateの接続はされていますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。

問題はそこでした。
接続することで、returnでのキーボードを隠す行為が
できるようになりました。

ありがとうございました。